# PHP - Add percentage to bitcoin values

Tags: php, calculator, bitcoin

I have a simple code in php and would like to add 3% on bitcoin value:

```
</PHP 
$price = "0.00001000"
$price_format = str_replace(".", "", $price);

echo ($price_format + ($price_format  / 100 * 3)); // 1030
?>
```

Return of my code:
**1030**

I need the return to be:
**0.0001030**

Does anyone know how I can perform this calculation by following the number of houses of the price?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how percentages work.  3% is 3/100, not 100*3.  To get 3% of X, multiply X by (3/100).  This is really more of a math question than a PHP question.

Comment: It's exactly what he does. The problem here is that PHP is not sure with types. He creates a string that reads "000001000" and then does the calc on that. I would suggest doing X*1.03 anyway. I would like to know what the str_replace is supposed to do.

Comment: So @OP you are deleting the comma from your number and get the result from that. That is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `number_format` when you multiply on the 3 percent to keep decimal places intact.  Multiply price by 1.03 (3%) and specify 8 decimal places.

```
<?php

$price = 0.00001000;
$new_price = number_format($price * 1.03, 8);

echo $new_price;
```

Here's a link to `number_format` for more info:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: worked fine, just do not understand why 1.03 is equivalent to 3%?

Comment: @Espector It isn't.  It is 103%.  Which is the same as originalValue + 3%